# promise.try vs promise.resolve error handling

Tags: promise, bluebird

I've been looking at bluebird promises and how promise.try differs from a promise.resolve.then when an error is thrown. Firstly some code using promise.try where it throws a synchronous error

```
Promise.try(function() {
    throw new Error('error');
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

secondly some code which throws a synchronous error on resolve

```
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    throw new Error('error');
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

As far as I'm aware they both behave the same. Is promise.try essentially a cleaner way of resolving the promise?

The docs says promise.try:

*will catch all errors in their Promise .catch handlers instead of having to handle both synchronous and asynchronous exception flows.*

In the case of the example given in the docs:

```
function getUserById(id) {
    return Promise.try(function() {
        if (typeof id !== "number") {
            throw new Error("id must be a number");
        }
        return db.getUserById(id);
    });
}
```

if the synchronous error is thrown the asynchronous code will never be reached. Would there be any difference if you put the code above in a promise.resolve().then(..)?

Any clarification/examples of promise.try will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to Bergi's answer: `Promise.try` is for those times you can't use `Promise.method`. The goal is to avoid cases where you have sync exceptions mixed with rejections.

Generally, whenever you're considering using `Promise.try` give `Promise.method` a spin.

```
var fn = Promise.method(function(){
    // can throw or return here, and it'll behave correctly
});
```

Is roughly the same as:

```
var fn = function(){
     return Promise.try(function(){
        // can throw or return here, and it'll behave correctly
     });
});
```

Comment: so if I need to choose between these two, use `Promise.try`

Comment: Depends on whether or not you're defining a method or just invoking one

Answer (score 8):

> As far as I'm aware they both behave the same.

Yes, mostly. However, the `.then(…)` callback will be invoked asynchronously, while `Promise.try` is synchronously executing your function.

> Is promise.try essentially a cleaner way of resolving the promise?

Yes, it does provide a cleaner (less confusing) notation. But it's more of an optimisation, because it doesn't create any `Promise.resolve(undefined)` in the first place.